# PHP preg_replace() clarification

Tags: php, preg-replace

Would anyone please be able to tell me why below code does work:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\[.*?\]/';
$string = 'INSERTED, Placement, 123, [status, companyUrl, hoursPerDay], 1984-05-15 05:00:35.167';
var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, 'null', $string));
// Prints 'INSERTED, Placement, 123, null, 1984-05-15 05:00:35.167'; which is the desired result.
```

and this one does not work:

```
<?php
// $pattern and $string the same
preg_replace($pattern, 'null', $string);
var_dump($string);
// Prints the original string unchanged, with the content between the square bracket instead of 'null'.
```

With regards to the not working example, I would have thought that "**If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or null if an error occurred.**" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-returnvalues)

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: The variable `$string` remains unchanged when calling `preg_replace()`. Instead the changed string [is return by this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-returnvalues).

Comment: Yes use `$string = preg_replace($pattern, 'null', $string);` or for a new one `$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, 'null', $string);`.